# Unable to insert data into db where a collection has a relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

This is in a `Node` project where I am trying to write a `graphql` api for a simple blog.

I am using `apollo` and behind the scenes attempting to save data to a `mongo` db via mongoose.

I am currently getting the following error when I try to save a Post data.

> "GraphQLError: ID cannot represent value: { type: "Buffer", data:
> [Array] }", "at GraphQLScalarType.serialize
> (/Users/name/projects/graphtime/node_modules/graphql/type/scalars.js:301:11)",

It is complaining about the Author insertion as part of the Post I believe.

Is there something wrong with my schema or how I am performing the query on the Apollo GraphiEditor?

The is the DB Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  avatar: { type: String },
});

export const Author = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  authors: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Author'
    }
  ]
});

export const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

This is the graphql Schema

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    authors: [Author]
}

type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    avatar: String
}

type Mutation {
    addPost(
        title: String!,
        authors: [ID!],
    ): Post
}
```

This is the grapql resolver.

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    addPost: (_, args, context) => {
      const newPost = new Post({
        title: args.title,
        authors: args.authors,
      });
      return newPost.save();
    },
  },
};
```

This is how I am querying in the editor which throws the error.

P.S: The DB already has an existing author in there and  lets say the id for that row is: `63babc44e18d174016b03433`

```
mutation {
  addPost(
    title: "New Post",
    authors: ["63babc44e18d174016b03433"],
  ) {
    title
    authors {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the authors field in your Post model. In your model, the authors field is an array of ObjectIds that reference documents in the Author collection. However, in your GraphQL schema, the authors field is defined as an array of Author objects.

To fix the error, you can either change the type of the authors field in your GraphQL schema to be an array of IDs, or you can modify your resolver to populate the authors field with the actual Author objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the mutation in this way:

```js
type Mutation {
    addPost(
        title: String!,
        authors: [ID!],
    ): Post
}
```

That's mean `addPost` return a `Post` object, which is:

```js
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    authors: [Author]
}
```

So `authors` is an array of `Author`s objects, not the `_id`s.

You are getting the ID and saving into DB but the returned object does not match `[Author]`. Also note how the `postSchema` is `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Referenced to Authors, yes, but is an array of IDs.

So you can return an array of IDs instead the Author object or populate the query in mongoose because you have the reference.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by - So you can return an array of IDs instead the Author object .

Comment: You can use `authors: [ID]` instead of `authors: [Author]` in the `Post` schema (if it fits in your business).